# Get the minimum value of a dataframe column with condition on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have these two dataframes :

```
dfX = pd.DataFrame({'Points':["A","B","C","D"],'Group':[1,2,1,3]})
dfX
  Points Group
0   A      1
1   B      2
2   C      1
3   D      3

dfY = pd.DataFrame({'Points':["A","B","C","D"],'Score':[2,3,4,5]})
dfY
  Points Score
0   A      2
1   B      3
2   C      4
3   D      5
```

I would like to get the minimum Score of Points sharing the Group of point C. Consequently, I would like to get 2.

*Because the point C is in the Group 1 and that the Group 1 is composed of points A and C, I would like to get the minimum Score between A and C, that is to say, 2.*

How could I do that in Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to merge the dataframes on the key `Points`, then get the group of point C, and finally take the mean of the scores within that group:

```py
merged = pd.merge(dfX, dfY, on='Points')
group = merged.loc[merged.Points == 'C', 'Group']
val = merged.loc[merged.Group.isin(group), 'Score'].min()
print(val)
```

```
2
```

Comment: And how please could I know which is the point having the minimum score (A for this example) ?

Comment: I found an answer to my previous question :
merged = pd.merge(dfX, dfY, on='Points')
group = merged.loc[merged.Points == 'C', 'Group']
df_group = merged.loc[merged.Group.isin(group)]
df_group[df_group.Score == df_group.Score.max()]['Points'].values[0]